# PHP variable combining issue

Tags: php

I am trying to concatenate a variable to my sql query in php to have my table sorted according to that variable.
For eg:

```
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'Val'){
   $query .= " ORDER BY val";
}
```

I need a variabvle $sortorder to be concatenated with this query. so that i get sorted query in ASC or DESC. What i do is

$order = ASC ;

```
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'Val'){
   $query .= " ORDER BY val" ."$order";
}
```

and write the logic for

```
if($order==ASC){$order= DESC}
```

and vice versa. but it doesnt work. table is not displayed. some syntax issue?

Anyone could help on  this. ?

Comment: What error do you get? What did you do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: "some syntax issue" - what is the issue? Any PHP or mysql errors?

Comment: You need a space between `val` and the sort order.

Comment: Are `ASC` and `DESC` defined constants?

Comment: If they are not constants, you should wrap them in quotes. `$order = 'ASC';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a space. Otherwise SQL will read `ORDER BY valDESC`

So:

```
$query .= " ORDER BY val " ."$order";
```

Or more compact:

```
$query .= " ORDER BY val $order";
```

You can check that your query is as expected by simply printing it

```
echo $query ;
```

This simple debugging can help you to resolve problem

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$query .= " ORDER BY val $order";
```

You need a space between the column name and the sort order. Your code was generating:

```
ORDER BY valASC
```

If you simply did `echo $query;` before trying to execute it, you would surely have seen this.  Please do some basic, obvious debugging before posting here.

Comment: Yes i resolved this now. I also need, once it is sorted in ASC, next time on click it is DESc. any points on that.. Thank you for your response